# Unable to Open then Dialog using Angular ngDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am unable to open the dialog box using `ngDialog`.
This is what my Function is in controller.js

```
(function () {
  var PersonController = function ($scope, $http, ngDialog ) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:49889/api/Persons").success(function (res) {
      $scope.person = res;
      $scope.Edit = function () {
        debugger;
        ngDialog.open({
          template: '<div><h1>I am Ng Dialog</h1></div>',
          plain: true,
          scope: $scope.person
        });
      }
    });
  }
  angular.module("MyApp").controller('PersonController', ["$scope", "$http" , PersonController]);
}());
```

I also added the dependency in main app.

Comment: what's the error you get ? how does your template looks like where you click to open the dialog ?

Comment: It seems that you've missed third injection parameter

Comment: cannot Read property open of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different problems here.

The first one, as Pavel responded, is that `ngDialog` is missing in the dependency injection.

The second thing is that you give a simple object (`$scope.person`) to the `scope` parameter. You need to give the full `$scope`.
Your code should become this:

```
ngDialog.open({
    template: '<div><h1>I am Ng Dialog</h1></div>',
    plain: true,
    scope: $scope
});
```

Comment: Thanks.I am getting the template div.now i have to add the bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

Try add ngDialog dependency in injection list:

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller('PersonController', ["$scope", "$http" , "ngDialog", PersonController]);
```

Comment: Tried this but again getting new error TypeError: j.scope.$new is not a function